# Python-Help in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need some help, I am coding a Zip password Cracker.I am trying to create a gui interface for  my cracker.
I want to show a message box for right password if founded in password file..
But, `showinfo` message box is not executing after clicking on crack button, while if i am printing password using `print` it is working..
So, help me why `showinfo` message box is not executing.
Here,

Comment: Never call Tk commands in a different thread than the one its interpreter is running.

Comment: @mmgp Could you pls explain that?

Comment: Your original question had example code which showed you were using threading. The current version of the question doesn't mention threading -- are you still trying to use Tkinter in a threaded environment, or have you changed your architecture?

Comment: @BryanOakley No i still want to use it, just finding another way to do that.. i think semaphore will do that for me, gonna try that to do my work.

if you have have founded any other way, lemme know

Comment: @lady: semaphores won't help. If you access Tkinter widgets from other threads you application *will* crash. The generally accepted  solution is to put requests on a thread-safe queue that your main GUI thread polls.

Comment: @BryanOakley & how to put requests on thread-safe queue ?

Comment: @Lady: http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Tkinter commands from any thread other than the main thread. Tkinter is not thread safe.

Comment: Actually, i am able to use the showinfo there & to execute it as well.. if am not creating root windows and button, & if execute main() directly.. then it is working ..

Comment: @Lady: you wrote "i am able to use the showinfo there". What do you mean by "there" - in the other thread? Your comment is confusing because your question says that showinfo _doesn't_ work.

Comment: @BryanYes, showinfo doesn't work for the code i have given there.. i am saying if remove the main tkinter winodw, & use showinfo button only for ehoing password to user after input from inpur from command lines it is working.

Comment: @Lady, and my point is, this sort of inconsistency in behavior is the type of thing that can happen when you use a non-thread-safe library from multiple threads.

Comment: okay, but if it is happening cz of importing non-thread safe library then why it was well working with tkMessageBox ?

Comment: @Lady: the problem isn't importing, it's calling functions that create widgets from two different threads.